# MySQL Counting different items in one query

Tags: mysql, select, count, where-clause, items

Let's say this is my DB table:
id, client_id, order_name

Every doubled order is creating new record. For example:

```
1, 1, super-glue
2, 1, super-glue
3, 1, plastic wallet
```

How do I found in single query, how many different items client ordered?

So it will return me 2 in this case.

I know I have to use `SELECT {something in here} WHERE client_id = 1` But I'm not sure about how to count different items.

Comment: Why 2 and not 1?  Please explain more

Comment: because there's two items with different names was bought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just count the different items for one customer you can use

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT order_name)
FROM orders
WHERE client_id=1;
```

If you want a summary count for every customer you can use a `group by` expression:

```
SELECT client_id, COUNT(DISTINCT order_name)
FROM orders
GROUP BY client_id;
```

If you want the latest row for every customer and order_name, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT id, client_id, order_name
FROM
(
  SELECT max(id) AS id
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY client_id, order_name
) single_orders
INNER JOIN orders ON single_orders.id = orders.id
ORDER BY client_id, order_name;
```

This would select the maximum id for each distinct customer-order-combination and then get the corresponding row data.

Finally, in MySQL you can also get a comma-separated list of the distinct items ordered by any customer:

```
SELECT client_id, group_concat(DISTINCT order_name ORDER BY order_name)
FROM orders
GROUP BY client_id
ORDER BY client_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use COUNT with DISTINCT order_name:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT order_name)
FROM yourTable
WHERE client_id = 1
```

Comment: What will this query return? 1st or 2nd record

Comment: oh ok i got it. Now i understood what the user wanted.

Comment: This will return 2, not the records. OP asked for a way to count them. This will tell you the number of "DISTINCT" order_names, and that's 2